# Dynamic graphic programming (Animation)

Tags: java, swing, animation, jlabel

I am trying to code a simple animation like a moving circle.  I have tried using `getGraphics()` and work with that but it's not dynamic and it's painted for just one time

So please help me and guide me to code a dynamic graphic program.

I mean for example defining a function and every time when it called, it draws a line on a label.

Comment: Please have a look at this answer [Ball Animation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9852739/1057230)

Comment: One more [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17586464/1057230), my personal favourite now a days by @MadProgrammer :-)

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help.

Comment: Here is an [SSCCE of dynamically changing an image](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10055306/418556), & [another one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10628553/418556) & [another one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11330719/418556)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to make a growing rectangle:

```
public class MovingRectangle extends JPanel {
    private Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            rectWidth += 100;
            repaint();
        }
    };

    private int rectWidth = 100;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
         super.paintComponent(g);
         g.drawRect(0, 0, 100. rectWidth);
    }

    public void start() {
        timer.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        timer.stop();
    }

    public void reset() {
        rectWidth = 100;
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `drawRect(...)` contains `.`, in place of `,`. But why `100. rectWidth`

Comment: That problem is fixed

Comment: thanks a lot!! solved!! but how do you use this class that you defined?

Comment: Do you know anything about swing? Do you use an IDE? If so, which one?  If you answer these questions, I would be happy to help.

Comment: not much! i just recently studied about swing and i use eclipse!

Comment: You have to create an instance of this class and add it to the frame's content pane. You'll understand what I mean once you understand swing.

Comment: I would like to see the results

Answer (score 1):

you should override the `paintComponent(Graphic g)`.
This method is called every time the `repaint()` is called, so you should periodic calling that method.

You should also set DoubleBuffering on true: `setDoubleBuffered(true)`
It will prevent possible flicker of your animation

Comment: There is no need to turn on double buffering. It is on by default.